# .vs showing as untracked file in git bash - what do i do?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-status, git-untracked

I have recently cloned a repo from git and havn't yet made any changes, all I have done is open the code up in VS19. In git bash i typed 'git status' and there is an untracked file im not sure what to do with. Can anyone suggest please?

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
    .vs/
```

Comment: Sound like (visual studio?) just creates that folder automatically to store config information. I think you can safely ignore it. Maybe add it to `.gitignore`

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#_ignoring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This directory is created by Visual Studio.  Add it to your `.gitignore` file.